# How To Customise WordPress Comment Submit Button?

Tags: theme-development, comment-form

I am trying to customise the output code of

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

At the moment the submit button outputs the following:

```
<p class="form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="486" id="comment_post_ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</p>
```

I would like it to output the following:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="486" id="comment_post_ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</div>
```

I now we can achieve this using css or jquery. But any solution using wordpress functions will be great.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a lot of form behavior by passing `$args` to the [`comment_form()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) function - have you tried that?

Alternatively, you can write a custom comments template file and then use the [`comments_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) call to display it within the theme. This method would allow you to have complete control of the type, class, and ID of any field, provided that you hooked in to the proper WordPress functions to handle comment submission.